# Ballerina module metadata documentation?

Tags: ballerina

In Ballerina Central, I see modules with keywords, version compatibility, authors, etc. I can't find any documentation on how to set anything other than the org and version in `Ballerina.toml`. Is there a full guide to how to set up all the module info hiding out there somewhere? I'd really like to warn people that the module I want to push is only compatible with the Swan Lake preview.

Comment: As far as I know users can only pull modules which are compatible with the Ballerina version they're using. This is validated internally, through the compiler and Central. The developer doesn't have to explicitly do anything to enforce it. Have you experienced a different behaviour?

Comment: So does the compatibility level get filled in automatically when pushing? How about the authors and keywords?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Ballerina.toml you can specify the module information as bellow.

```
orgName= "hevayo"
Version= "1.2.3"
license= "Apache-2.0"
authors= ["hevayo"]
keywords= ["ballerina", "Twitter", "endpoint", "connector"]
repository= "https://github.com/hevayo/module-twitter"
```

A more detailed explanation can be found at [Ballerina spec](https://github.com/ballerina-platform/ballerina-spec/blob/master/project/project-spec.md) repo.

To warn people about the compatibility you can mention it in Module.md file which will be used to generate the module page in ballerina central.

Comment: Thank you-- that's the documentation I was looking for!